# Difference between pdflatex \input{filename} and pdflatex filename

Tags: pdftex

There is a user (https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19356/kiss-my-armpit) which claims in the profile that it is best practise to

> Use `pdflatex \input{filename}` instead of `pdflatex filename`.

What is the difference between the two? Naively I would have expected that both are the same...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual case is

```
pdflatex filename
```

In that case, the filename is read by the system specific commandline reading of the tex executable, so the behaviour of non-ascii characters in the filename is system dependent but probably works if the filename works with other system commands such as listing the directory.

with

```
pdflatex \input{filename}
```

then the line will be passed tex's normal input buffer. There was one latex release at the beginning of last year when the default UTF-8 processing would mean that non ascii letters would not work in this context, however the timing of setting up UTF-8 typesetting processing was adjusted so that this form now works the same way.